# Show that a function satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann function if and only if $\frac{df}{d\overline{z}}=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

The full question is "Define the operator $\frac{d}{d \overline{z}} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{d}{dx}+i\frac{d}{dy})$. Show that a  function $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equation if and only if $\frac{df}{d\overline{z}}=0$." I have already figured out the $\rightarrow$ direction and only need help with the $\leftarrow$ direction.

So far I have: Let $\frac{df}{d\overline{z}}=0$ and $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$. Then $$0=\frac{df}{d\overline{z}}$$ $$=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}(u+iv)+\frac{i}{2}\frac{d}{dy}(u+iv)$$ $$=\frac{1}{2}(u_x-v_y)+\frac{i}{2}(u_y+v_x)$$ And this is where I get stuck. I am not sure where to go from there so any help would be much appreciated. (Also feel free to fix my formatting I know it is atrocious."

Comment: A complex number is zero if and only if both, its real part and its imaginary part, are zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $$\frac{1}{2}(u_x-v_y)+\frac{i}{2}(u_y+v_x)=0=0+i0.$$ The real and imaginary parts are the *real* numbers $\frac{1}{2}(u_x-v_y)$ and $\frac{1}{2}(u_y+v_x)$, which thus are zero, giving the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Ahh yes I see! Thank you so much! It is always annoying when you get through the hardest part of a proof and get stuck on the simplest part!

Comment: Quite true. :-) ---